# Protractor test to upload image file

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am writing tests in protractor which a JS-based framework and selenium test stack for running tests. I am facing an issue where I have to test file upload

```
var fileToUpload = '../../snn.jpg',
absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
var photoUpload = element(by.xpath('//[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div'));
await photoUpload.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

I got the error:

> Failed: element not interactable

Comment: Does this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724933/protractor-failed-element-not-interactable answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that uploads are happening on `input` tag. You're trying to upload on `div`